# jQuery .change don't work

Tags: input

I have a link, and onclick the value is send in the input. but the function .change not work in my input after click.

```
$('#about').change(function(){

            if($('#about').val().length == 0 ){
              $('.etape').addClass('gray');
           }else{
            $('.etape').removeClass('gray');
            $('.info').toggle('1000')
           }

   });
```

Comment: According to https://api.jquery.com/change/, the change event is not fired until the input control loses focus. This may be why you are not seeing an event when the control is first clicked on

Comment: It is the problem !but i don't know how to make